# State of Web SQL - can I use it in a mobile project?

Tags: mobile, web-sql

I am using [Web SQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) for my app that I intend to run on iOS and Android. It's coded in jQuery Mobile and will be translated to a native app using PhoneGap.

Since I heard that Web SQL is kind of deprecated and will maybe no longer be supported, I am wondering if I will be able to still use it in my environments (iOS and Android)?

At the moment things work.

If I should migrate to another solution, what would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use it in your projects. I use it for my mobile web app where I use jQuery Mobile and Phonegap to put an app on iOS and Android and things work just fine.